# MATLAB error using "diary"

Tags: matlab

I'm learning MATLAB and for my homework am supposed to use the diary feature to save a file from the command window. I used the following code,

```
%% 2.21

clc
clear

diary( 'degrees.dat' )

columnOne = linspace(0, 180, 8);
columnTwo = columnOne .* (pi / 180);
D_to_R = [columnOne', columnTwo']

diary off

clc
clear

load ( 'degrees.dat' )`
```

and got the error:

Error using load
Number of columns on line 3 of ASCII file
degrees.dat must be the same as previous
lines.

I put the above code in the editor window but tried putting it directly in the command window and it didn't make a difference. The code up until loading the saved file seems to work fine and I can't see a difference in number of columns like the error indicates. 
Any ideas?

Comment: `diary` puts all text from the command window in an ASCII file. `load` is used for loading variables, typically from a file in `.mat` format, or optionally from ASCII with a specific format, which is not what you get in your diary file. The diary file is not normally meant to be processed by Matlab. What did you expect `load('degrees.dat')` to do?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `diary` correctly.  However, your use of `load` is incorrect, and most likely unneeded based on the problem at hand.  You've shown that you can save a file with 'diary'.

If you want to show the contents of your diary as stored in the file `degrees.dat` in the command window you can type, into the command window:
`type degrees.dat` or `type('degrees.dat')`.

Similarly, if you want to open it in the edit window you can use
`edit('degrees.dat')` or `edit degrees.dat`

Comment: The diary is a good way to keep track of what you were entering into the command window, a history that you can go back and look at for your records.  You will most likely learn ways of saving and loading data later on.